# Avoid the property 'width' into several blocks

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 4 different colors like this:

[image]

My problem is that, I often use the property `width: 25%` into several blocks. It is possible to avoid the repetition ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="color">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="aqua"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.color{
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
}


.red {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}

.aqua {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `flexbox` then you can just add a common class in all flexbox items and add `flex: 1`;

```css
.color {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <div class="box red">red</div>
  <div class="box aqua">aqua</div>
  <div class="box green">green</div>
  <div class="box blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes just add a second class to each element you want to affect.

```
<div class="color">
  <div class="red block"></div>
  <div class="aqua block"></div>
  <div class="green block"></div>
  <div class="blue block"></div>
</div>
```

```
.block {
  width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use grid on the color div like:

```
.color {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
.color > * { width: 25%; }
```

It assigns the 25% width to all *direct* child elements of `.color`

There's no need to add anything to the HTML code that way and no need for additional classes.

```css
.color{
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
}

.color > * {
  width: 25%;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <div class="red">a</div>
  <div class="aqua">b</div>
  <div class="green">c</div>
  <div class="blue">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.color div`. This selects all div under the class name color. Read more on [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information.

```
.color div {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```css
.color {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color div {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="aqua"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra class and give it to all the parts:

```css
.color{
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
}

.part {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <div class="part red"></div>
  <div class="part aqua"></div>
  <div class="part green"></div>
  <div class="part blue"></div>
</div>
```